# Error with getting date from excel in php

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a excel document with a `date` column, containing values like `1-Dec-13`, however, when I read this file in via PHPExcel, I am getting `float(41609)`. So, any idea how to get the proper date back from 41609? or why the heck is 41609 in the first place?

My code to read in the excel:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$rdata = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$rdata = $rdata->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

Comment: Excel stores dates as sequential days since Jan 1, 1900. 1/12/2013 is 41609 days since 1/1/1900. You should be able to do some calculations from there, depending on what you mean by *proper date*.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is:

```
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

An MS Excel date/time serialized value is a floating point number, identified only as a date or time by the number format mask that's applied to the cell. In setting readDataOnly as true, you're telling PHPExcel to read only the raw data, and not to read any formatting information such as the number format masks, so PHPExcel has no idea whether a cell contains a float that should be interpreted as a date/time or simply a float.

Remove that line, or use

```
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(false);
```

instead; and PHPExcel will handle the dates and times for you.

Otherwise, you'll need to explicitly identify which cells contains dates and times yourself, and use the helper methods in PHPExcel_Shared_Date to convert the values to Unix timestamps or PHP DateTime objects manually, and then use standard PHP date functions (or the DateTime object methods) to format them yourself